# What is the equivelent of this.toSource() on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have some code that only works on Firefox because this.toSource() doesn't work on Safari and Chrome. How can I make a alternative function that works on Safari, Chrome, and some of the other Browsers. Ive tried to replace it with this.toString() and it wouldnt work heres my code

```
var elements = [];
var rect = function() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 100;
    this.background = "black";
    this.name = "rect"
};
rect.prototype.render = function() {
    if(this.toSource() != null) {
        elements[elements.length] = this.toSource();
    }
    // c = this.toString();
    // elements[elements.length] = c;
    var returnThing;
    for(var i in this) {
        returnThing += this[i]
    }
    returnThing = returnThing.replace(/NaNblackrect3D30/g, '');
    returnThing = returnThing.replace(/function()/g, '');
    returnThing = returnThing.replace(") {", '');
    elements[elements.length] = returnThing;
};
```

Comment: Why do you need `toSource`? What are you using it for?

Comment: I want to export the rect objects attributes to the elements array